# Only allow ldap users to connect to Inspircd

Tags: ldap, irc

I've set up Inspircd for our IT shop and I'm trying to configure it to be closed except for LDAP users. I used `./configure --enable-extras=m_ldapauth.cpp` and I configured the LDAP module in `modules.conf` with my LDAP server settings. I am still able to connect to the server with any user, how do I restrict this?

It doesn't seem like enabling LDAP authentication precludes any other methods. The connect options in `inspircd.conf` seem like possibly the way to do it, but none of the tags seem relevant for that. Using Inspircd 2.0.18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it figured out.  I didn't have the ldapauth module actually loading from the configuration file.  Once it's loaded I am only able to login using ldap authentication.